# php mail() function and HTML in message

Tags: php, email

Can someone refer me to a good tut or site that shows how to create a simple HTML mail message using the PHP mail() function...

thanks

Comment: You could look at the source of the excellent [`phpmailer`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Comment: Did you take a look at the example on the [`mail` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for an HTML email?

Comment: No offense, but you have to be more specific. Just asking us to point you to a tutorial is just plain lazy given the abundance of [search results here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+html+mail+with+php) and on [Google](http://www.google.de/#q=sending+html+mail+php)

Comment: Problem is there are so many of them, and they get all crazy with mime types, and chmodroot and all of this linux jargon that doesnt apply... some are from 2003 and some are just not very intuitive...so thats the direction i was looking for... i wasnt being lazy. If i was lazy i would have asked for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Swiftmailer: http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Swiftmailer is fine, modern and based on PHP 5. +1